# Passing a variable by reference to a callback function used in array_walk

Tags: php

*For the example I'm using here, I realize I can use array_keys, but I am trying to learn how to use things like array_map and array_walk.* In this case, array_walk().

I'm trying this piece of code

```
$inventory = [
    'Apples' => ['Golden Delicious', 'Granny Smith','Fuji'],
    'Oranges' => ['Valencia', 'Navel', 'Jaffa']
];
$fruits = [];
array_walk($inventory, 'fruitTypes', $fruits);

function fruitTypes($value, $key, &$fruits) {
    $fruits[] = $key;
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Warning: fruitTypes(): Argument #3 ($fruits) must be passed by reference, value given
```

line 8 is:

```
array_walk($inventory, 'fruitTypes', $fruits);
```

But if I change line 8 to:

```
array_walk($inventory, 'fruitTypes', &$fruits);
```

I get the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "&", expecting ")"
```

Any idea how I can pass the $fruits array by reference in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look one more time on this example:

```
<?php
$fruits = array("d" => "lemon", "a" => "orange", "b" => "banana", "c" => "apple");

function test_alter(&$item1, $key, $prefix)
{
    $item1 = "$prefix: $item1";
}

function test_print($item2, $key)
{
    echo "$key. $item2\n";
}

echo "Before ...:\n";
array_walk($fruits, 'test_print'); //<< callback function

array_walk($fruits, 'test_alter', 'fruit'); //<< callback function and argument
echo "... and after:\n";

array_walk($fruits, 'test_print');
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Before ...:
d. lemon
a. orange
b. banana
c. apple
... and after:
d. fruit: lemon
a. fruit: orange
b. fruit: banana
c. fruit: apple
```

**Description**

> array_walk(array|object &$array, callable $callback, mixed $arg =
> null): bool

Here is the source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

Comment: I've already seen this in http://ww.php.net, but I don't see how it addresses my question. What I would like to pass by reference is not the array I am walking. I want to pass the $arg by reference.